# salesforce core package - unable to see envelope status object when envelope is sent as draft

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I'm using Docusign's apex toolkit to generate an envelope within my sfdc instance.

I need to initially create the envelop as draft, so I'm using the `dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope` with the sendNow flag on false.

Executing this call creates the envelope as draft on Docusign, but I'm also expecting a record from `dfsle.Envelope.Status` custom object to be automatically created, so I can track envelope status, and this record is not created.

I've tested that if I `sendEnvelope` with the `sendNow` flag on `true`, then the status record is created.

Also tried creating the status record manually on my sfdc instance using the envelope docusignId, but the record is not updated if I send the envelope from outside sfdc.

Does anyone know if this is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the design of the application the status record is created immediately only if send now is true during the send envelope call.

However, you can use dfsle.StatusService for dynamically fetching the status of an envelope as well updating it back to salesforce automatically.

Please use the explanation provided in step 5 in the following link
https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/code-examples/salesforce-sending-signing-template

Comment: Vineet, using dfsle.StatusService.getStatus for envelopes on draft status returns always empty. 
I'm trying to manually create the dfsle__EnvelopeStatus__c record now and use the dfsle.StatusService.createStatus call to bind my local record to the envelope status on docusing. 
Have you succedded to track status of draft envelopes within sfdc ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the status records are only created when the envelopes are actually sent. When they are created in draft state the status is not synced back since there are no triggering events for update in the connect settings. However, there is an envelope record that gets created on the Envelope object with an empty Sent time which should be an indication that the envelope was not sent.

Comment: I see, so If I rely on the creation of the envelope record within my sfdc instance, do you know if any update on that envelope outside my instance will be synced back to sfdc? 
In my scenario I might have  another user sending the envelope from Docusing's site. Will this action be reflected as a status change on sfdc? Should a status record be automatically created at that time?

Comment: The status record will only be created from envelopes sent from salesforce using the out of box Send with DocuSign functionality or using the Apex toolkit. If envelopes are just created as draft from Salesforce or via the Apex toolkit and then are being sent out from the web app they wont sync back to salesforce